# How to set an image of navigationbar every where in the app

Tags: objective-c, ios, navigation, storyboard

I'm building an app with storyboard. Now I want on every screen in my app the same topBar/navigationbar. I want to set an image on this navigationbar. After some searching, I found this code.

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"topbar.jpg"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

I've put it right above my implemantation in my appdelagate.M file. But it is not working.
Also does anybody knows if this is working in IOS 5.1 as well?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `UIAppearance`. It allows you to change attributes across entire UI classes. For example, I have this in an app:

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavBarBackground.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:img forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

`UIAppearance` was introduced in iOS 5. The "old" way to do this was to override `-drawRect:` using a category for the class in question (e.g. `UINavigationBar`), as you did. ("Swizzling" -- exchanging your method for an SDK-provided method -- not required, by the way.)

I found, when iOS5 came out, that the `drawRect` trick didn't work, so I had to use `UIAppearance` conditionally by enclosing the above code in an `if` statement like so:

```
if ([[UINavigationBar class] respondsToSelector:@selector(appearance)]) {
    ...
}
```

Why conditionally? We continued to support iOS4, so iOS4 users would experience a crash if we didn't conditionalize this `UIAppearance` stuff. And so, we had both this and the `drawRect` solution in the app!

If you don't have to support iOS4, you should definitely look into `UIAppearance` to achieve your goals here.

Answer (score 0):

I used to swizzle drawRect for this purpose, you can perform swizzling at `+initialize` with `method_exchangeImplementations` (runtime.h). Now the tricky part is to call the original drawRect, as the methods are swizzled you'll need to use the custom drawing method `name` to call the original one. Like if you do the drawing with, you'll have `[super customDrawRect:rect];` at the end

```
- (void)customDrawRect:(CGRect)rect { 

   ... 
   [super customDrawRect:rect];
}
```

---

```
#import <objc/runtime.h> 

@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

+ (void)initialize {

    Method originalDrawRectMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(drawRect:));
    Method customDrawRectMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(customDrawRect:));
    method_exchangeImplementations(originalDrawRectMethod, customDrawRectMethod);
}



- (void)customDrawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"topbar.jpg"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];

    // original drawRect call
    [self customDrawRect:rect];
}


@end
```

Comment: I'm very sorry but I don't understand anything you are say. Do you have maybe a more detailed code example ?

Comment: I've added the code but it's up to you to check it and please let me know id you find and solve any issue so that i could edit the text for the others. You might read about methods swizzling at http://cocoadev.com/wiki/MethodSwizzling or look for any other source, there's quite a lot.

Comment: Thank you but It gives the following error on [self customImageDrawRect:rect]    ERROR:  No visible @interface for 'UINavigationBar' declares the selector 'customImageDrawRect:'

Comment: Oh right, that is because the method name is customDrawRect and there's a parameter missing.